# Exporting data from excel to word, While function

Tags: excel, vba, export, ms-word

I am trying to export data from a excel to word but something goes wrong at the begging of the while statement. For some reason I get an error at the line `ReDim Preserve zPList(zIndex) As personClass`, the error is `Subscript out of range`.

Can someone help please?

```
Public Sub GetExcelData(ByRef zPList() As personClass, ByRef zIndex As Integer)

    Dim tempStr As String
    tempStr = ""
    Dim row As Integer
    row = 2

    While tempStr <> "zzz"

        zindez = zIndex + 1
        ReDim Preserve zPList(zIndex) As personClass
        Set zPList(zIndex) = New personClass

        Range("A" + CStr(row)).Select
        zPList(zIndex).fname = ActiveCell.text

        Range("B" + CStr(row)).Select
        zPList(zIndex).lname = ActiveCell.text

        Range("C" + CStr(row)).Select
        zPList(zIndex).Email = ActiveCell.text

        Range("D" + CStr(row)).Select
        zPList(zIndex).phoneN = ActiveCell.text

        row = row + 1
        Range("A" + CStr(row)).Select
        tempStr = ActiveCell.text

    Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: In this case to debug you should have a look at zIndex. Possible it is less then 0? If not, then you should post the code that DIM the zPList initially and initializes zIndex and calls the Sub GetExcelData.